# PHP Excel Reader : get strikeout / strikethrough value

Tags: php, excel, parsing

I am looking for way to parse the strikeout / strikethrough value of cells in an Excel sheet, using if possible a PHP script. The cells that are strikeout or not contain simple text values (no formula or anything).

I have try using http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/ and a few others scripts. But I have not found any PHP script that parse this specific value (strikeout) and I have try without success to add this parsing feature to the php-excel-reader.

I have try to add the following :

```
function lineTrought($row,$col,$sheet=0) {
    return $this->fontProperty($row,$col,$sheet,'strikethrough');
}
```

And also add some code to this part of the parse code (indicated by **) :

```
            case SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_TYPE_FONT:
                    $height = v($data,$pos+4);
                    $option = v($data,$pos+6);
                    $color = v($data,$pos+8);
                    $weight = v($data,$pos+10);
                    $under  = ord($data[$pos+14]);
                    **$strikethrough  = v($data,$pos+16);**
                    $font = "";
                    // Font name
                    $numchars = ord($data[$pos+18]);
                    if ((ord($data[$pos+19]) & 1) == 0){
                        $font = substr($data, $pos+20, $numchars);
                    } else {
                        $font = substr($data, $pos+20, $numchars*2);
                        $font =  $this->_encodeUTF16($font); 
                    }
                    $this->fontRecords[] = array(
                            'height' => $height / 20,
                            'italic' => !!($option & 2),
                            'color' => $color,
                            'under' => !($under==0),
                            'bold' => ($weight==700),
                            **'strikethrough'=>$strikethrough,**
                            'font' => $font,
                            'raw' => $this->dumpHexData($data, $pos+3, $length)
                            );
                    break;
```

But I can't find the right data that indicate the strikethrough value. v($data,$pos+16) is incorrect and I have try a bunch of other stuff without any success.

If not possible with a PHP library, any idea on how I could parse my XLS with a Python or Perl script and then switch the data to PHP?

It seems like Spreadsheet::ParseExcel-0.55 from CPAN Perl script might work but my main application is PHP so I would need to write result to a file and parse it back in PHP or something like this.

Comment: How does strike-through text look? is it encoded? binary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also check out: http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel

it says it could read Excel files. i was using it mostly for writing, so I don't know to what extent reading is supported.

Comment: Seems to be a very complete library, I'll try it. I do not understand how I did not found this one. Me fail.

Answer (score 0):

With PHPExcel (http://phpexcel.net, official url) you can read the style value from cell. For strikethrough it is something like this.

```
$cell->getStyle()->getFont()->getStrikethrough().
```